# How to add a Global.asax file to ASP.NET MVC5 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to find a solution to enable me to add a `Global.asax` file in Visual Studio 2015. I created an ASP.NET MVC project, but there was no `Global.asax` file present, hen I right click with my mouse on MyApplication -> Add -> New Item -> C# -> Web.

Is it possible to do this in VS 2015 in this way?

Comment: If you created an MVC project, Global.asax is added by default. If you accidently removed it from the project, you can see if it's still on the filesystem and try to add it back using Add > Existing Item... Otherwise, I'd just create another new MVC project and copy it over from there.

Comment: Ok, but how can I add this file if I created Empty app?

Comment: Create a new MVC project and get it from there. Honestly, starting an MVC site from an entirely empty project requires so many changes, it's silly not to just let VS scaffold it for you in the first place. There's more than just Global.asax; you'll have to set up routing, bundling, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try showing all files as shown in the picture and see if Global.asax is there - right click on file -> Include in project

[image]