# Something is seriously wrong with my ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, httpcontext, global-asax

I have been programming ASP.NET Web Forms for a long time and recently decided to learn ASP.NET MVC.

However, I am clearly having some issues that I cannot tell how. No one that I have come across in web had the same problems.

### #1: Web.config issues

When I first created my MVC project in VS2019, there was no web.config so I added it via **project > add new item> Web Configuration File.**
All I needed it for was to store my connection string. When added it had only two lines of code:

```
<configuration>
</configuration>
```

I added my connection string and the file looked like this:

```
<configuration>
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connection" connectionString="myconnectionstringblablabla" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

In my controller I tried to fetch the connection string by doing,

```
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;
```

And this happened:

[image: Error]

Same things happens when fethcing AppSetting keys from web.config.
Is web.config not meant to be used for ASP.NET MVC?

### #2 Global.asax

Unlike web.config, Global.asax file doesn't even show up on the **add new item menu**:
[image: add new item menu VS19]

Tried this solution: [How to add a Global.asax file to ASP.NET MVC5 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766964/how-to-add-a-global-asax-file-to-asp-net-mvc5-project) Didnt work either.

### #3 Session & HttpContext

In ASP.NET Web.Forms, I would normally use Session variables like this:

```
Session["ClientID"] = somevalue;
```

I can't do that in ASP.NET MVC, although I have seen people doing it.

Also I can't access to HttpContext from a non-controller class:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["mycookie"];
```

It throws *HttpContext does not contain a definition for 'Current'...*

====================================
Is Something wrong with my program. I don't know how to check if I am using correct references or assemblies, but I think I am missing something.

Please help

Comment: Are you creating a Net.Core project? Or one using the Net Framework 4.X? The setups of the two environments are totally different. It seems that you are handling with a Core one. So you have overlooked a crucial step in the guided wizard that creates the project from a template

Comment: @xandune: Seems like you are using ASP.NET Core MVC. If so see the following article: [Migrate configuration to ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1)